# How to perform anomaly classification in multivariate time series when anomalies appear in different time windows?

Tags: time-series, classification, anomaly-detection

I'm dealing with anomaly classification in multivariate time series.
However, in my problem, the different classes of anomalies can be detected when considering different time windows. That is, some classes can be detected by considering just a couple of hours, ad others can be detected only by considering a week.

What are the best approaches for dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at MERLIN, they solve exactly this.

For example in fig 13, some anomies are of length 5 hours, some are up to 48 hours.

[https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/MERLIN_Long_version_for_website.pdf](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/MERLIN_Long_version_for_website.pdf)